# What Capacitor do I need? (if any)

Tags: capacitor, dc, radio, 12v

I have a airplane with a radio and other electronics. When I transmit on my radio the voltage drops about 0.3 volts across my other electronics and causes some sensitive sensors to read incorrectly. It was suggested to me to install a capacitor by my radio to help reduce the voltage drop.

The plane has a 12v battery and when the engine/alternator is running its at about 14.4v.  The radio draws a max of 6 amps during transmission according to the manual.

I am trying to figure out what size/type of capacitor to install. I'm open to other suggestions as well.

This probably sounds like a caveman is asking. I'm a pilot, not an electronics guy. Please be kind. Thanks

Comment: How do you know the sensors are not actually affected by emissions from the antenna when transmitting?

Comment: I don't. But I don't know how I can resolve that either if it's the case.

Comment: Do the sensors read incorrectly when the alternator kicks in i.e. if the voltage increases from 12 volts to 14.4 volts does that cause a sensor problem? My form belief is that you find the source of the problem rather than take guesses.

Comment: Radio draws 6 Amps when transmitting, but for how long?  This duration would determine the capacitance required.  If 0.1s, the capacitor would be very small.  If 60 seconds, the vehicle would be too heavy to fly due to this capacitor.

Comment: Seems unlikely that a small drop like that is enough to significantly affect sensors. Maybe there is an issue with the antenna or radio installation that is causing interference.

Comment: Hello and welcome: what are the "sensitive sensors"?

Comment: There isn't enough info to propose a solution. We'd need schematics and ideally oscilloscope screenshots of the voltage drop.

Comment: As a test, temporarily power the radio separately (disconnected from your main power, and connected to another additional battery), and check for the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As a very rough calculation, let's say you want to get a capacitor that can deliver 6A for 10 seconds, and only drop its voltage by 0.1V.  That's 60 x 10 / 0.1 = 600 farads.

We're in supercapacitor territory here.  And you would need a supercapacitor bank, as the individual capacitors aren't rated for 15V or so.

But the big question is why would any electronics designed to run off a 12V battery and an alternator malfunction if the voltage drops by only 0.3V?  Even the output of an alternator isn't guaranteed to be that accurate.  It should be 14.4V under ideal conditions, but if it's charging a nearly flat battery and powering electrics at the same time, it could be as low as 13.8V and still be within specification.  If the alternator has failed and you're running on battery only, you could be down as low as 11V before the battery is considered flat.